# org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine: org.apache.avro.reflect.Pair620b9c15f622a7

Tags: serialization, avro

I have a class as given below

```
class A
{
private   Map<Long ,Set<Long>> x;
private   Map<Long ,Set<Long>> y;}
```

When avro tries to create schema using reflection it creates the schema having the name of the map as Pair620b9c15f622a7 for both the fields. ANd hence I get the exception

```
Schema s = ReflectData.get().getSchema(A.class);
```

I am not sure as of why I am getting this error , though the field names are completely different.

1 solution for this might be to explicitly define the name of x and y in the schema using @AvroSchema annotation, but that is very manual task and I have to do it for all such mappings in my code

Answer (score 0):

pretty similar to what I just answered here [Generate Avro file based on java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700725/generate-avro-file-based-on-java-file). TRy using kite sdk util class