# Generate Avro file based on java file

Tags: java, avro, avro-tools

There are plugins that can generate java file using Avro schema. Is there a reverse of that? I would like to generate Avro schema based on java file.

Comment: Have you found one?

Answer (score 1):

Kite SDK has a lot of useful things to work with Avro Schema. Take a look to this

http://kitesdk.org/docs/1.1.0/Inferring-a-Schema-from-a-Java-Class.html

Answer (score 0):

Late reply but may be helpful to someone who reach here.
You can use avro maven plugin

```
mvn avro:induce
```

Generate Avro files (.avsc and .avpr) from Java classes or interfaces